# getting the project path

Tags: jsf-2

I can't get the path of my project. I have tried many ways but the result is the path of the directory of eclipse and I don't know why.

Note that I didn't create the project, I imported it.

Here is what I have tried:

The first :

```
private String destination = new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"\\";
```

The second:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
File file2 = workspace.getRoot().getLocation().toFile();
private String destination = file2..getAbsolutePath()+"\\";
```

The third:

```
private String destination=System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

All of these methods didn't work for me and I don't know why.

Comment: Normally, you should never need to know it. Even more, in some environments it's even impossible (webapp is deployed fully in RAM memory instead of in local disk file system). What exactly is it, the problem for which you incorrectly thought that this would be the solution?

Comment: First of all, is there supposed to be `..` here: `private String destination = file2..getAbsolutePath()+"\\";` Should it be: `private String destination = file2.getAbsolutePath()+"\\";`?

Comment: it's a typing mistake. does any one know why it returns eclipse directory ????.

Comment: Solved!!!. go to Run --> Run Configurations... --> choose type of your project on the left --> select arguments tab on the right --> Working directory --> other: type(${workspace_loc:project_name}) .